# uploading file to nancy without having it seek through the stream

Tags: multipart, multipartform-data, restsharp, nancy

I'm trying to upload a file to nancy using RestSharp. I use request.AddFile() that uses multipart request to upload the stream to a nancy server.

The issue is, while Nancy is parsing the request to pass it to the module it seeks through the whole stream, defeating the purpose of the stream (I want to stream the file directly to disk).

I went through the nancy source code and found where it does that,

in [`HttpMultipart.cs`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/HttpMultipart.cs) it tries to get all of substreams using `GetBoundarySubStreams()` which calls into `GetNextBoundaryPosition()` and that method basically seeks the stream.

I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong? maybe I haven't configured something? is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an ages old question, but can you please try out this:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
Request.Body.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

AFAIK, this seems to be streaming the file stream directly to disk.